# Appending and Replacing String Text

Tags: python, append

**I'm currently in a Python Scripting course and I'm struggling with a lab.
This is the prompt:**
Many user-created passwords are simple and easy to guess. Write a program that takes a simple password and makes it stronger by replacing characters using the key below, and by appending "q*s" to the end of the input string.

i becomes !
a becomes @
m becomes M
B becomes 8
o becomes .

Ex: If the input is: mypassword
the output is: Myp@ssw.rdq*s

**My Issue: I can't figure out how to add the "qs" at the end of the new password so instead of it being p@ssw.rdq*s, my code is running p@ssw.rd**

**I've managed to get this**:

```
word = input()
password = ''

for character in word: 

    if(character=='i'):
        password += '!'
    
    elif(character=='a'): 
        password += '@'
        
    elif(character=='m'): 
        password += 'M'
        
    elif(character=='B'): 
        password += '8'
        
    elif(character=='o'):
        password += '.'
        
    else:
        password += character


print(password)
```

Comment: Have you tried `password += "q*s"`?

Comment: After the for loop can't you just do `password += "q*s"`

Comment: I'm just wondering why there's like 3 identical answers all posted at different times.

Comment: More like 5 with the comments.

Comment: true, sounds like copy/paste day ;-)

Comment: At least I can say mine was there first ;)

Comment: The reason is because many people answered the question at the same time, seconds after it was posted. I wrote my answer about 36 seconds after it was posted, and by the time I had clicked post there were already 2 comments with answers, after refreshing there were even more.

Answer (score 1):

Just before you print the password, add `password += 'q*s'`, outside of the for loop.

This will add the `q*s` after all other characters have been processed.

Comment: vote for this one as he was definitely the first ;-)

Answer (score 0):

after your for-loop, you can add:

```
password += 'q*s'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and add: password+='q*s' .After your for loop